# Filter a data frame in accordance with the values ​assumed by the sidebar panels

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following panels:

```
# ui.R
# rest of the code
selectizeInput(
  "year",
  "Select a year",
  choices = c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007),
  multiple = FALSE
),
selectizeInput(
  "indicators",
  "Select the indicators",
  choices = c("Economics", "Society", "Politics", "Culture", "Tourism"),
  multiple = TRUE
)
# rest of the code
```

Now, in `server.R` i want to filter a data frame in accordance with the previous choices. Is the following way correct?

```
observeEvent(c(input$anno, input$indicatori),
  {
    df %>% filter(YEAR == input$year & INDICATOR %in% as.vector(input$indicators))
    # rest of the code
  }
)
```

Comment: You're asking if one way is "correct".  Does it work?  If it works, then it is correct.  Otherwise, you could ask for help about why it doesn't work.  If/when you do so, please include a reproducible example that includes some data so we can test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a `reactive` dataframe, instead of `observeEvent`.

Updating the `reactive` automatically updates all plots and tables :

```
filtered_data <- reactive({
  df %>% 
    filter(YEAR == !!input$year & 
           INDICATOR %in% as.vector(!!input$indicators))

})
#output$myplot <- renderPlot(plot(filtered_data()))
#output$mytable <- renderTable(filtered_data())
```

Note the use of `!!` before using shiny inputs in `dplyr`